# Can we use onGloballyPositioned for calculating the height of this component in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to calculate the height of this yellow component. I was trying to get using:

```
.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                 Log.v("positionInRoot", coordinates.positionInRoot().y.toString())
            }
```

I'm not sure I'm doing the right way or not.

[image: screenshot]